# Fragment disappear after coming back from startActivityForResult

Tags: android, fragment, onactivityresult, android-nested-fragment

i have a strange problem.

i use nested fragment in my code,( 4 level )

Home  -> Services ->  ServiceDetails -> Upload

in the last fragment ( Upload Fragment ) i want to choose image from the gallery or the camera so i wrote the following code to pick the image :

```
switch (which) {
    case galleryItem:
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, “Select Album”,
                Home.GALLERY_REQUEST);
        break;

    case cameraItem:
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,
                Home.CAMERA_REQUEST);
        break;
```

and every thing is ok.
i can get URI from the selected picture in `onActivityResult` of my fragment with the following code:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == Home.GALLERY_REQUEST) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

        } else if (requestCode == Home.CAMERA_REQUEST) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            Uri cameraUri = getImageUri(
                    getActivity().getApplicationContext(), photo);

        }
    }
}
```

**Problem**

if i open my album and scroll ( see all thumbnail ) in that, after selecting my picture `onActivityResult` called in the fragment but fragment is not visible any more and `Home` fragment ( first fragment ) be visible in my app.
but if i open album ( by startActivityForResult ) and immediately select photo, all thing is going ok.

i don’t any problem with camera.

i searched a lot but don’t find any helpful data,
if you want to see any part of my code tell me.
i don’t get any crash just i lose my last fragment.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem has been solved by changing

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setType("image/*");
 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
 startActivityForResult(
        Intent.createChooser(intent, “Select Album”,
        Home.GALLERY_REQUEST);
```

to :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, Home.GALLERY_REQUEST);
```

i don't know why but if any one know what is different between starting intent by `Intent.createChooser` and normally call tell me, thanks

Comment: Same problem i faced, Intent.createChooser use when multiple intent calling and merging.

Comment: This does not fix the issue. Please elaborate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Explicit call from fragment to onActivityResult function as follows

In Parent Activity class, override the onActivityResult() method and even override the same in Fragment Class and call as the following code.

In Parent Class:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.dualPane);
fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

In Child Class:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   //in fragment class callback
    }
```

Comment: thanks for response but as i said in my answer i don't have any problem to getting data from `onActivityResult` ,

Comment: it is a common problem for the nested fragments. so you can manage the fragments call or showing fragment that you want in child class.

Of course this is the hack but it should do the trick for now.
Other than that i am trying putting same kind of code so i will update you once i find an actuall solution.

Comment: i don't get you, did your mean is i must open all child fragment in code ? like in onResume check one boolean values and open desire fragment ?

Comment: Hardik i get my answer, thanks for times and solution.

Comment: How did you do that can you give me your solution?