# Android fragment disappear when return from startactivityforresult

Tags: android, android-fragments, startactivityforresult

I have an android predefined navigation drawer activity named as **MainActivity**.
From that on addUser button click **AddUserFragment** is showed. There is a button addImage when i click on that it startAnActivityForResult. And from gallery when i pick the image instead of returning to **AddUserFragment** it take me back to **MainActivity**.
Thanks in advance!.

Comment: Please add your Code, And also Check this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27592556/3949810
Hope it may help

Answer (score 0):

for pick image from fragment start intent in this way:

```
  Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                           android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
  startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, 1);
```

and handle the result in this way:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                           selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();


            Bitmap yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: do all command in fragment